# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) in php, Angularjs website

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

We are working on an application and it is having below technologies:

**At Local System**
PHP 7.1 (what xampp provides on local system)
Codeigniter 3.1.3
AngularJS v1.2.16

At Shared Server
PHP 5.6 (On Shared Environment)

This web application is working fine at local system but after upload it is giving below error in chrome inspect element:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

http://backoffice.website.com/user_roles_con/index_function/list_all_roles

Object
config
:
Object
data
:
"Access denied.↵"
headers
:
(name)
status
:
403
statusText
:
"Forbidden"
__proto__
:
Object
```

What we have already tried is to change permission of application folder and files to 0755 and this is what the best I tried to debug.

We also tried to change version of PHP to 7.0 in our control panel, this has not solved the problem but all other website hosted have stopped working.

Now we are completely clueless, please suggest some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Directories should have the permissions 0755 but files should have 0644.

Comment: I have made all files to have 0644, but the error is same.

Comment: I think this can be server security issue too, not a just file system access permissions one. The url may be secured by the htaccess or on the server side script.

Comment: @neptune We have checked htaccess, it seems ok to me. Please let me know where I can find server security check.

Comment: if you need any additional info, please let me know.

Comment: Any workaround?